# Fullcalendar setting custom business hours per resources

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I was wondering if there is a way to set the availabilty of a resource in a custom way like
9:00-13:00, 15:00-19:00, every day could be different anyway.
According to [doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours-per-resource) I can set business hours but there is only one startTime and endTime.

Comment: The main business hours docs suggests you can specify an array - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't been clear, I 'd like to have two or more availability in the same day 9:00-13:00 AND 15:00-19:00

Comment: Yes. The documentation seems to suggest that it would be possible. I can't test it right now though. Have you tried?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I've tried [here](https://codepen.io/LorenzoNet/pen/rNMVgWg). Even if it worked I need to customize every day!

Comment: that isn't using the array pattern shown in the documentation though is it? Look again at the example in the link I added, and look carefully at the syntax, compared to your attempts. It should not be hard to copy it.

Comment: e.g. I'd expect something like `businessHours: [
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    startTime: '08:00',
    endTime: '10:00'
  },
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    startTime: '14:00', 
    endTime: '16:00'
  }
]` should work

Comment: That's right, I've update the code and it works in that way. My use case is more complex, every week the timetable could be different. Maybe disabling the month view and catching the week scrolling event I could customize the view.

Comment: if the business hours are per resource, then if you want to change the hours, you need to  ensure the resources are re-rendered. So yes you definitely can't use the month view if you want different business hours each week. Normally though, business hours is used to represent relatively fixed times, such as opening hours for a shop or something - which rarely (if ever) change. If you have such variable requirements, it might be better to use [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) for your purpose.